# Drivers in labview

Tags: interface, labview, drivers

we need to interface Rohde & schwarz fsv30 spectrum analyzer to the laptop. we are using windows 7 opering system. labview version is 13.0f2, 64 bit(2013). For that we have downloaded instrument driver related which is related to Rohde & schwarz fsv30 spectrum analyzer in the website ***www.rohde-schwartz.hu/hu/service_and_support/Downloads/Drivers.*** In that link we found drivers for so many instruments. Among them We have downloaded the driver which related to r&s fsv labview. The name of the folder is like this **rsspecan_lv_331**. we unzipped the files and we got instr.lib and user.lib. **C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2013** we copied the files in this file path Under instr.lib and user.lib. But we didn't get the drivers under instruments i/o -> instrument drivers. Is the installation is correct or not. If it's not correct what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

After downloading **rsspecan_lv_331** we will get **instr.lib** and **user.lib**. In instru.lib **Rohde&Schwarz Spectrum Analyzer** folder will be there. Copy that folder into ***C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2013\instru.lib***(this is different from the above file instru.lib). In user.lib **_express** folder will be there.In that folder **rsspecan** will be there. Copy this folder into ***C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2013\user.lib_express*** into this.(this user.lib is different from the above file user.lib). Then in instrument drivers in functions palette we can get the rhode&schwarz spectrum analyzer driver.